# LINQ orderby and group

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following code

```
var res = from d in CalEntries
    group d by d.date.ToString("MMMM") into grp
    orderby grp.Key 
    select grp;
```

I have a list of objects in CalEntries where one member property is `date` of type `DateTime`. Currently this code returns me all the dates grouped by the month name however the order of the groups is alphabetic so November would appear before October for example. 
How can I modify this query to retain the grouping on the month name but to order the groups based on the months chronological order?

Comment: Does it matter if you put your orderby after your groupby? MSDN says `Datetime.Month` is a number, so it should be ordering by correctly using that.

Comment: Sorry my original LINQ code was incorrect. Have updated

Answer (score 2):

It is really backwards to group by the name of the month if you don't care about the month name at all. Instead, group directly by the month number and sort by it. Don't compute with strings if the native format of your data is more suitable.

```
group x by x.Month into g
orderby g.Key
select new { MonthName = g.Key.ToString("MMMM"), Items = g.ToList() }
```

Comment: The month name is significant. Its being displayed in my XAML. I have a ListView that is bound to the group and the Key is being used as the group header. If there is a way to order by the month number and still have access to the month name in the XAML then this sounds like a good approach

Comment: Just format the date as a month name like you previously did, but in the appropriate place. Not during grouping and ordering. You seem to have all required knowledge already. Any concrete problems?

Comment: Yes I'm struggling to work out how to modify the key to set the formatting. I can't do it in the XAML as the TextFormat isn't supported on a data bound textblock so it needs to go on the LINQ statement. I'm just not sure how to do that while still returning a `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, CalEntry>>`

Comment: Does it have to be an IGrouping? Could you return an enumerable of a custom type? Instantiate that type in the final select of the query. You can format there.

Comment: I believe it does have to be an IGrouping, yes.

Comment: That is unlikely. In that case, group on `new { MonthNumber = x.Month, MonthName = x.ToString("MMMM") }`. That makes `g.Key` contain the number to sort on and the name to display.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
orderby d.date.ToString("MM") ascending
```